# Using PyMongo insert_many and empty/null values

Tags: python, mongodb, null, pymongo, bulkinsert

I'm in the process of populating a mongoDB database and and not sure what to do with null values when using the insert_many statement (I should state at this point that I'm new to both Python and MongoDB)

The data I am inserting is two dimensional traditional SQL like data obtained from a text file, it looks something like this:

```
emp  = [
         [7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', null], 
         [7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839],
         [7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839],
         [7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839],
         [7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566],
         [7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566],
         [7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902], 
         [7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698],
         [7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698],
         [7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', 7698],
         [7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN', 7698],
         [7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788],
         [7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698],
         [7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 778]
       ]
```

And my database population looks like this

```
employee.insert_many([{
                       "_id" : emp[i,0],
                       "Name": emp[i,1],
                       "Role": emp[i,2],
                       "Boss": emp[i,3]
                      }
                      for i in range(len(emp))
                      ],False)
```

Ideally I would like "KING", the president, to not have the "Boss" field but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you show some lines from your data file?

Comment: It's shown in the original posting as a two dimensional list above called "emp"

Comment: I see that. will be nice to see the file so we can create a code to read from it and integrate it with the insert_many code. I can give n example based on your data, but not sure if it is the best.

Comment: Sadly I can't show the exact data as it has IP value to the company I'm working for (hence the very short example). I have added more data above just in case it's useful

Comment: Hope my answer will give you some hints.

Comment: you are calling insert_many many times, while insert_many is used to be calle once, using a lsit of documents to insert